# display text using ajax and php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm just trying to do a simple thing in ajax but it does not work. 
I just want to display a text when i click on the input button

**ajax.js**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('#insertForm').change(function(){
//on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
var req=$('#insertForm').val();
//requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "lib/function.php",
  data: "insertForm="+req,
  dataType : "html",
  //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
          alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
      },
      //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
  success:function(data){
    $('.coucou').empty();
    $('.coucou').prepend(data.coucou)
  }
});
});
});
```

**html.php**

```
<div class="coucou"></div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs" name="insertForm" id="insertForm" style="margin-top: 5px;;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span>
</button>
```

**function.php**

```
if(isset($_POST['insertForm'])){
    echo "coucou";
}
```

Comment: set data in inside ajax `data:{ insertForm: req}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#insertForm').click(function(){
    //on recupere la valeur de l'attribut value pour afficher tel ou tel resultat
        var req=$('#insertForm').val();
        //requête ajax, appel du fichier function.php
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "lib/function.php",
          data: "insertForm="+req,
          dataType : "html",
          //affichage de l'erreur en cas de problème
          error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                  alert(XMLHttpRequest + '--' + textStatus + '--' + errorThrown);
              },
              //function s'il n'y a pas de probleme
          success:function(data){
            $('.coucou').empty();
            $('.coucou').text(data);
          }
        });
    });
});
```

You need to use `.click()` and not `.change()` and also, in the success, you receive only a string not an object so you just need to write data directly (with `.text()`)

Copy my code because i have also add `;` that you had forgotten. (It's work, I tested)

Another point you use `.val()` on `#insertForm` but there is no value attribute in your html. So `var req` is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

You have a `button` element not input type button and `button` element does have text content, you can change to this:

```
var req=$('#insertForm').text();
```

but still i feel you don't have any text in the button then what do you want to post exactly.

---

Problems:

1. `button` element has text content instead of value.
2. `datatype:"html"` is expecting some html in the response.
3. `data.coucou` in the success function is expecting json data.